# Canvas Line Width changes when canvas width changes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I don't know if there will be a solution to this.

I have a canvas element which I wish to change the width of.  That's easy enough, I know, but when the width changes, the lines in the drawing also go thinner/thicker when the width goes narrower/wider.

I could probably get around this by redrawing the image and playing around with scaling and lineWidth, etc, but I do not want to re-draw every time the width changes (I am changing the width using setInterval, so I don't think redrawing every 40-50 - or less - milliseconds is a reasonable/doable solution).

Can anyone think of a way to get around this?

A simple explanation to explain, I have:

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
ctx.lineWidth=1;
ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 400, 400);
```

So when the width of canvas changes, the lineWidth becomes less than 1 pixel, to a point where it becomes "broken" and disappears.

In writing this question I am think more and more that the only solution would be to redraw the image but please let me know your thoughts.

ADDITION***
I am using this to change width, hope it makes sense:

```
repeater = setInterval(function() {
    $(".action").css("width", originalWidth - borderRight - borderLeft + (mouseX - clickX));
}, 40);
```

I check when mouse is over right edge of canvas, then on "mousedown" originalWidth, borderRight, borderLeft, mouseX and clickX are set outside of repeater, so as mouse moves left and right the width increases/decreases.  The interval is cleared on "mouseup", of course.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: How do you change the width of the canvas? There is a right way and a wrong way to do this.

Comment: Okay, fair comment!  I am using setInterval and changing the width using jquery .css("width", newWidth).  It is a custom resize function that I have done.  I will update my question to hopefully explain a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use CSS to rescale a canvas. When you use CSS, you scale the output of the canvas in the HTML layout, but don't change the internal resolution.

Change the width and height attribute of the canvas HTML node instead.

Comment: Thanks for this.  How would you change the setInterval function?  I have tried changing .css to .attr and also tried document.getElementById("action").setAttribute("width", newWidth) - in this instance changing "action" to be an ID and not a class, of course -  and the drawing seems to disappear when doing both?  Am I misunderstanding you, would you mind elaborating on your answer?  As you can tell, I'm no expert at this.

Comment: Although, when logging to height to console after it disappears, the height has changed, however the drawing is no longer there...  if that helps figure what I have done wrong?

Comment: @Mike, changing the width or height of a canvas element will clear it, you then need to redraw the whole thing again. But Philipp is right, don't use CSS to resize a canvas element.

Comment: @Mike When you want to preserve the canvas, you could draw the content to an off-screen canvas and draw it back after resizing. Although depending on how you built you application, redrawing might be faster.

Comment: @Kaiido - okay, thanks for this.  So the only solution would be to redraw then?  I wanted to try and avoid doing that, that's why my question asks if there is another way.  Sorry if I have confused anything and thanks for your help.

Comment: The example I included is very simple.  The actually drawing is quite complex, would redrawing this every 40ms not be too much, would it affect the smoothness of the change?  I want it to be seemless, that's why I was trying to avoid redrawing.

Comment: @Mike, there are several ways to redraw it though. As Philipp just told you, you could redraw to an off-screen canvas (not appended to doc) and redraw on the on-screen one after you changed its size. Or you could create a draw function and call it again on resize.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you need to actually change the canvas element height/width and not only the drawing sizes. Anyway, in your situation, what I would do would be to first draw on an off-screen canvas, then adjust the width/height of drawn one using `ctx.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, x, y, width, height)` on mousemove. `ctx.drawImage()` can be called @ 30fps without much trouble on most devices, even for 1080p images.

Comment: @Kaiido, okay.  Thanks for your help.  I am learning and I appreciate your comments.  Drawing to an offscreen canvas is something I will consider.  I asked the questions initially because I was concerned about redrawing simply being too much to handle, so I appreciate your explanation.  Thanks both of you, appreciate the help!